# React-native enable Hot Reload Exception

Tags: react-native

I get an exception when I activate the hot reload in react-native.

I have tried to delete node_modules and reinstall them all with `npm install` but that has not resolved my issue.

My package.json file contains this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I just run into this myself. Exactly same error message. If i switch back to `Disable Hot Reloading` it goes back to normal ... humm ..

Comment: Just to confirm upgrading to `"react-native": "^0.24.1"` solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You are on 0.22 of react-native.

There was some errors with hot-reloading in this version that have since been fixed. Most of my errors went away when I upgraded to 0.23. And more errors have been fixed since then.

I would recommend upgrading to react-native to 0.24.

If you are on Windows I would upgrade to 0.23 until [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7068) issue is fixed. The issue is fixed in 0.25, but that is still a release candidate.

Comment: I'm in Mac but i would not to upgrade because i have many npm packages that not work with 0.24. Thank you for your response.